# Methods for find common roots of two functions

Tags: functions, roots

Are there any methods for finding the common roots of two functions? I would like to know if such a method exists, which doesn't involve finding all the roots of both functions.

While I'd like to find one which can be applied to any two functions, I'm also interested in methods that only consider specific cases, such as finding the common real roots of two polynomial functions.

Comment: If $r$ is a common root of $p(x)$ and $q(x)$, then $r$ is a root of $a(x)p(x)+b(x)q(x)$. Somerimes there are nice choices for $a(x)$ and $b(x)$.

Comment: When $f$ and $g$ are polynomials you can use the [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The common roots of two real functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are the roots of $f(x)^2 + g(x)^2$.

---

To see why this is true, first notice that if $f(x) = g(x) = 0$, then $f(x)^2 = g(x)^2 = 0$, and the sum must also be zero.

Now suppose $f(x)^2 + g(x)^2 = 0$.  Remember $f(x)^2 \geq 0$ and $g(x)^2 \geq 0$. The only way the sum of two nonnegative numbers can be zero is if the nonnegative numbers are both zero.  Thus $f(x)^2 = 0$ and $g(x)^2 = 0$.  This implies $f(x) = 0$ and $g(x) = 0$.

Comment: Could you explain this a bit, or link to a source?

Comment: @akukas: I fleshed it out.  Hope that helps.

Comment: It is helpful, thank you. I assume that I could also use $|f(x)|+|g(x)|=0$?

Comment: Yes, that would work. A benefit of my versions is that if $f$ and $g$ are differentiabke at the shared root $x$, so is $f(x)^2 + g(x)^2$.